# Prevent form re-submit after refresh

Tags: php, html

I've been reading some on other question regarding this that i should use the header( 'Locaction: xxx.php' ); but i can't figure out how to implement it to my code. I'm sorry for bad explaination on this. Any help or guiding i would be most greatful! This is the index.php below:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="upload">
        <div id="logo"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png"></a></div>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="uploader.php">
        <p class="uploadtxt">Choose your file below:</p>
        <input type="file" name="image" class="button" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload It!" class="button" />
        </form>
    </div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the uploader.php code below:

```
<?php
// Set local PHP vars from the POST vars sent from our form using the array
// of data that the $_FILES global variable contains for this uploaded file

$fileName = $_FILES["image"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["image"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["image"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["image"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true

$url = "http://localhost/";

// Specific Error Handling if you need to run error checking

if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
} else if($fileSize > 10000000) { // if file is larger than we want to allow
    echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 10000000kB in file size.";
    unlink($fileTmpLoc);
    exit();
} else if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {
     // This condition is only if you wish to allow uploading of specific file types    
     echo "ERROR: Your image was not .gif, .jpg, .jpeg or .png.";
     unlink($fileTmpLoc);
     exit();
}

//-- GENERATE A RANDOM NAME --//

$newfilename = rand(0, 999);
$newerfilename = $newfilename .'-'. $fileName;

//-- MAKE UPLOADS FOLDER IN YEAR AND MONTHLY --//

$path = "uploads/";

$year_folder = $path . date("Y");
$month_folder = $year_folder . '/' . date("m");

!file_exists($year_folder) && mkdir($year_folder , 0777);
!file_exists($month_folder) && mkdir($month_folder, 0777);

$path = $month_folder . '/';

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $path . $newerfilename);

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Localhost - Upload Completed!</title>

<?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="upload">
        <div id="logo"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png"></a></div>
        <p class="filenametxt"><?php echo "The image is now uploaded!"; ?></p>
        <p class="uploadtxt">Get the link below:</p>
        <pre><?php echo $url . $path . $newerfilename; ?></pre>

    </div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, you do not want to redirect since the info in upload.php needs to be shown to the user

Comment: I don't understand what your question is?

Comment: The question is how to accomplish this. When i'm using the header('location: uploader.php'); it give me errors. So if there are any other options of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['key']) ? $_POST['key'] : rand(1,150)); ?>" />
    <?php if (isset($_POST['key']) { $_SESSION['key'] = $_POST['key']); } ?>
```

And in your submission PHP:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['key'])) { if ($_POST['key']==$_SESSION['key']){ echo "You may not resubmit a form!"; } } ?>
```

Comment: I'm totally a beginner on PHP. Can you give me an example where i would put the code. I'm feeling lost.

Comment: Where I said "Try this:" - put that under your:
`<input type="submit" value="Upload It!" class="button" />`
And where I said "And in your submission PHP:" - put that under your:
`<?php`

Comment: Thanks. But i got an parse error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: What line did PHP say it was on? :)

Comment: It was on 18, the line that you wrote = `<?php if (isset($_POST['key']) { $_SESSION['key'] = $_POST['key']); } ?>`

Comment: `<?php if (isset($_POST['key'])) { $_SESSION['key'] = $_POST['key']); } ?>` Update it to that :)

Comment: I'm getting: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'` on line 18.

Comment: I'm an idiot! `<?php if (isset($_POST['key'])) { $_SESSION['key'] = $_POST['key'];) } ?>`

Comment: There's not...
if **(** isset _(_ $_POST['key'] _)_ **)**